# laravel authorization ability check too few arguments

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

blade:

```
@can('see_similar', $similar, $in_pair)
...
@endcan
```

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Gate::define('see_similar', function ($user, $similar, $in_pair) {
        return count($similar) > 0 && (isset($in_pair)) && $in_pair !== 'in_pair';
    });
}
```

It gives me this error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::App\Providers{closure}(), 2 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php on line 452 and exactly 3 expected (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/daters.blade.php)

Though it works if I pass just one argument "...function($user, $similar)" for example. I tried to pass an array of args, didn't work.

Please explain to me how can I pass several arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc:

> Gates always receive a user instance as their first argument, and may
>   optionally receive additional arguments such as a relevant Eloquent
>   model

Your problem is that you are passing 3 parameters to the closure function, you need to remove one.

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    // Here you MUST pass at most 2 parameters
    Gate::define('see_similar', function ($user, $ELOQUENT_MODEL) {
        return $what_you_want; // A boolean value
    });
}
```

Comment: according to the doc there is no way

Comment: Could you pass an object as the second argument? That object could contain as many collections/variables as you wish.

Comment: @party-ring will try

Answer (score 0):

Barmaxon, your `boot()` is ok!

You need to check `web.php` if your route has `->middleware('can:see_similar')`

I have removed it and then could pass many variables:

```
public function abc()
    {
        $x=1;$y=2;
        $this->authorize('see_similar',[$x,$y]);
        return view('abc');
    }
```

Or you can leave `->middleware('can:see_similar')` in routes and edit your `boot()`

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Gate::define('see_similar', function ($user, $similar=null, $in_pair=null)....
```